# AXML layouts not updating in designer VS2017 Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I'm not sure if it's something I'm doing or not, but the scenario is this....

When I create multiple layout-* (i.e. layout, layout-ldpi, layout-xhpdi, etc) folders and place the AXML files in each of the folders....  double click to open them in the designer... it DOES change the "device" selection for the display correctly, BUT the actual visual display DOESN'T change.... making it VERY difficult to see how multiple screens are going to handle the layout files (i.e, no matter the selection I make on the layout nodes on the left).

I know in older Xamarin Studio versions it did update the layouts where I could make the necessary changes, but not any more.

Im not sure if it's some setting, or something I'm missing, but I need it to work. :)

If anyone can lead me in the correct direction to fix this it would be awesome!

Comment: I've tested it in VS2017 latest update. The layout changes. Could you please try update VS to the latest update? And maybe some codes together with some pictures to describe the problem.

Comment: I just created the simple test project.... 3 layout folders.... 
layout
layout-ldpi
layout-xxxhdpi

Even though I have different text for each layout, clicking on the different screen layout icons for the proper folder doesn't change the visual layout on the screen (it only shows the initial one it loaded up... but the simulated "Nexus" devices show it being changed).

I did update to the latest version last night and no difference.
I can email the sample if I knew where to send it. But it's very easy for me to recreate (like I said unless I'm doing something wrong somewhere).
--Eric